# scanf and loops with multiple inputs - c

Tags: c

How can I make my program accept multiple inputs ( using `scanf` & loops) & print the results respectively after calculations?

My program accepts six inputs but only displays one output. I would like to get the following output: [image: sample output I want].

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    main() {
        // Declaring variables
        char name[25];
        int hours, rate, gross, bonus, counter;

        printf(" A program to determine the gross pay for six Employees\n Please Enter the Name, No. of hours worked and hourly rate respectively\n");

        for (counter = 1; counter <= 6; counter++) {
            scanf("%s %d %d", &name, &hours, &rate);
            gross = hours * rate; // determining the gross pay
            printf("%s %d %d %d\n", name, hours, rate, gross);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `scanf("%s %d %d",&name,&hours,&rate);` --> `scanf("%s %d %d",name,&hours,&rate);` or `scanf("%s %d %d",&name[0],&hours,&rate);`

Comment: `main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: You can define a `struct` to hold that information, then an array of that `struct` can hold the information for a number of employees.

Comment: Tip: Rather than describe the output "but only displays one output.", better to post the exact output received.  Good to post what you want, better to post what you want as text than as a picture.  Post the input used too.

Comment: If your input was "Jane 39 10.00\n" "Henry 40 10.00\n" ... then the present answer will not fix your issue.  Posting your sample input will help.  Not posting input leaves this post unclear.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by @LPs in comments. 
Change following line
`scanf("%s %d %d",&name,&hours,&rate);` 
 to this 
 `scanf("%s %d %d",name,&hours,&rate);`
 or 
`scanf("%s %d %d",&name[0],&hours,&rate);`

Comment: You do not need &name[0] - name will do

Comment: but is &name[0] is wrong?? . I know name will do. Please correct me if i am wrong. @edHeal . That is why i have mentioned it in or statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() { //it must be int main()
    // Declaring variables
    char name[25];
    int hours, rate, gross, bonus, counter;

    printf(" A program to determine the gross pay for six Employees\n Please Enter the Name, No. of hours worked and hourly rate respectively\n");

    for (counter = 1; counter <= 6; counter++) {
        scanf("%s %d %d", &name[0], &hours, &rate); //you are reading string as input, use either &name[0] or name (base address)
        gross = hours*rate; // determining the gross pay
        printf("%s %d %d %d\n", name, hours, rate, gross);
    }
    return 0; //on successful completion 
}
```

Comment: You do not need `&name[0]` - `name` will do